# sorting a tree-like structure with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has a tree like structure, where the level of a node is determined by the indentation, as you can see below.

[image: Tree]

My objective is to iterate over this sheet, and sort it given some hardcoded order (f.e., Mike:1, November:2, Lima:3, Oscar:4, Tango:5). In my situation, I want my output to be:

```
Mike
November
Lima
    ALL OF LIMA'S CHILDREN AND GRANDCHILDREN
Oscar
    ALL OF OSCAR'S CHILDREN AND GRANDCHILDREN
Tango
```

Where the tree structure is preserved, and the values associated with every name on the columns to the right are also maintained. How would I go about implementing this in VBA?

Comment: That's a *very, very* broad subject. VBA doesn't have any built-in tree data structures, so you will need to parse your data into, well, a tree-shaped data structure. Then manipulate that tree. You'll want to define a `TreeNode` class; if a `TreeNode` needs a reference to its parent node, then [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/202414/23788) will probably be useful.

Comment: Excel doesn't have trees. It has rows and columns. Organize your data accordingly, with named ranges, and sort based on those named ranges.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon is it not possible for a quick parse based on indentation, without the need for a special data structure? It's almost simply moving certain parts of the sheet up and down. It's only the top and bottom of the subtrees that matter.

Comment: Parse into what? If you need to model a tree, you'll want to parse it into a tree. If you're trying to custom-sort a pivot table, then custom-sort a pivot table; if this data comes from a table, work with the data off the table instead; it'll be much easier than trying to sort this data by scanning lines and computing their indentation without involving tree nodes.

Comment: If what you want to do for a large set of data is to convert your indent levels into a number you can work with, then you'll need VBA, specifically `{range}.IndentLevel`